# Multiple domains different static pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, seo

I have my main domain `domain.co.nz` with a static homepage of `home` but I also have a url that is great for SEO purposes and what I am trying to do is work out how I can have my `seoDomain.co.nz` point to a specific static page with the related information but the rest of the site remains `domain.co.nz`

Comment: If you're trying to host multiple domains on the same server, you can use Apache's "virtual hosts" to respond to requests for a given domain.

Comment: @yttriuszzerbus I am thinking interms of SEO and what would be the best way to do it

Comment: you could create another host for the other domain and put your special SEO page under that host.

Comment: @yttriuszzerbus thats what I was thinking or a redirect

Comment: A redirect may be worse seo-wise, as a temporary redirect would likely be ignored, and a 301 moved permanently would cause search engines to update their index to the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood well here's what you should do, in the part of the site that you want to display information from another page use the PHP's built-in `include()` or `require()` function and set its value to a $_GET variable(if you want the users to bookmark it) to include the other page from the domain. But this is really risky and insecure for your site so before doing that i recommend you to google `Remote File Inclusion/Local File Inclusion` prevention before doing any of the above.

Comment: include()ing or require()ing remote pages is ok, but can I just stress that users could, if you include() based on input, do /somepage.php?include=somepage.php which would cause an infinite loop and jncrease server load, leading to potentially easy Denial-of-Service attacks.

Comment: You can prevent that by processing whats passed in the include variable.